# Open Graph debugger fail page after adding meta description

Tags: html, facebook, macos, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

My Open Graph markup worked great up until about two years ago and then stopped at about the same time as I moved from my old Mac to a new one.
To isolate the problem I have made a page that just contain the bare minimum of tags and that work.

See: http://www.skofeber.se/og-test-produkt-ok.html

But if I try to add other basic tags like a meta description tag the Facebook Open Graph Debugger will report errors even though nothing has changed in the OG-markup.

See: http://www.skofeber.se/og-test-produkt-fail.html

The only difference between these two pages is that the second one has the following tag (and also the og:url is changed to be correct)

```
<meta property="description" content="FooBar" />
```

"FooBar" can be any text, the result is the same.

The FB OG Debugger will now report:

```
Object at URL 'http://www.skofeber.se/og-test-produkt-fail2.html' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
```

and

```
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.`
```

It will also display `Response Code 0` instead of 206 that it shows for the first page that works.

The same thing happens if I replace the meta description tag with:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

The W3C HTML checker report no errors or warnings for either page.

I use BBedit on Mac to write the pages and they are served via Mac OS X Server built in Apache.

This is the markup I use that only work if you delete the last line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:title" content="FLAMINGO-801LG, Pleaser - Skofeber" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.skofeber.se/og-test-produkt-fail.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.pleaserusa.com/picxnw/flamingo-801lg-cbg.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Skofeber" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1828455913" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1866414943596562">
<meta property="og:description" content="Skor, stövlar och högklackade i alla modeller och storlekar. Över 3 000 modeller från Pleaser, Demonia, Fabulicious, Funtasma, Bordello, Pin Up Couture, Pleaser Day &amp; Night och Devious" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="6R2MYVKMcuGQTOjcexRK7BkomqpJGwoyNZ4gPaaHAEc" />
<meta property="description" content="FooBar" />`
```

Comment: Have you used the developer tools in your web browser to ensure that all the expected tags are actually in the page?

Comment: Why do you have this last line? What happens when you replace your last line with the following: `<meta name"description" content="FooBar" />`?

Comment: @keith-m No not in my browser but I have used W3C HTML checker and when i validate both pages there and have it show the source all the tags that I put in my page show up and there are no errors or warnings.

See: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.skofeber.se%2Fog-test-produkt-fail.html

Comment: @unor I want the page to have a proper meta description tag since thats good for SEO from what I know. If I use the tag you suggested the W3C HTML Checker reports errors and warnings. 
The Facebook Open Graph Debugger still reports the same errors as with my meta description tag.

See: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.skofeber.se%2Fog-test-produkt-fail2.html

Comment: @unor your missing an "=" for the name attribute ;)

Comment: I now fixed the missing "=" in the tag @unor suggested so now it is OK in the W3C HTML Checker but still the same errors in the Facebook Open Graph Debugger. See: http://www.skofeber.se/og-test-produkt-fail2.html

Comment: @DavidBergquist: (As Keith M noted, I missed the `=` in my comment) If you talk about the standard HTML meta description, then you *have* to use `name` instead of `property`, i.e.: `<meta name="description" content="FooBar" />`. If you use `property`, it’s RDFa and not the plain HTML meta tag, and `description` would then be part of a vocabulary which you would have to specify.

Comment: @unor Well, that's fixed in this version but the FB OG Debugger (as I wrote above) gives two errors `Object at URL 'http://www.skofeber.se/og-test-produkt-fail2.html' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.` and `The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. `. Both are there, it's like the debugger just don't read them.
See: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.skofeber.se%2Fog-test-produkt-fail2.html